# Problems with openni_tracker launching

Tags: openni, openi-tracker

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am trying to use `openni_tracker`. I have `ros-fuerte-openni*` installed. `roslaunch openni_launch openni.launch` is working properly and I can see the image in `rviz.` However, when I run `rosrun openni_tracker openni_tracker`, initially there was the following error.

```
Find user generator failed: This operation is invalid!
```

I googled for the solution to this problem and was instructed to install NITE-bin-dev-linux-64-v1.5.2.23. Now the error has change to the following.

```
Find user generator failed: Can't create any node of the requested type!
```

Any help?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/130891/problems-with-openni_tracker-launching/) by [Latif Anjum](https://answers.ros.org/users/4454/latif-anjum/) on ROS Answers with karma: 79 on 2014-02-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I see you posted new answers [here](http://answers.ros.org/question/48060/running-openni_tracker-with-multiple-kinects/?answer=130976#post-id-130976) and [here](http://answers.ros.org/question/42654/openninite-incompatible-in-fuertegroovy-on-precise/?answer=130991#post-id-130991).  Just FYI, that's really not how this site should work; the answers are really for answers, not new questions.

Based on all of your information I have several pieces of advice.  First, I already mentioned you should update NITE on one of your comments.  After seeing this question, I see you already did that.  On Fuerte and 12.04, I just tried `openni_tracker` with NITE versions 1.5.2.23 and 1.5.2.21 and it worked with both.  During my testing I noticed that if I run `openni_tracker` before starting up the Kinect/Asus with `openni_launch`, I get  the same error you are seeing.  **So first hint, make sure the device is running and publishing point clouds before starting the tracker.**

Second hint: based on the second comment I linked above, you are getting a bunch of `ELFCLASS` warnings in the output of `niReg -l`.  This sounds to me like you installed the x64 version of NITE, but you are on an x86 system.  Try installing [NITE-Bin-Dev-Linux-x86-v1.5.2.23](http://www.openni.org/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/NITE-Bin-Linux-x86-v1.5.2.23.tar.zip) instead.

---

Originally posted by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) with karma: 9031 on 2014-02-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Latif Anjum](https://answers.ros.org/users/4454/latif-anjum/) on 2014-02-19**:
Thank you sir. Your suggestion to install NITE for x86 worked. Sorry for posting on multiple questions, will be careful in future.

**Comment by [gaussian](https://answers.ros.org/users/21014/gaussian/) on 2015-01-07**:
@jarvisschultz Please tell me a solution for this error
`InitFromXml failed: Can't create any node of the requested type!` 
I get this if I run openni_tracker .

**Comment by [anilmullapudi](https://answers.ros.org/users/26823/anilmullapudi/) on 2016-07-18**:
i was getting same error, `InitFromXml failed: Can't create any node of the requested type!`
any clue how to resolve this please